# Using dot notation appended to generic function in Xcode autocompletes to (τ_0_0), what does this mean?

Tags: xcode, swift

I was working on a function with a generic parameter; for the purpose of this question, say

```
func foo<T>(a: T) { }
```

When writing a call to the function, I mistakenly added a dot `.` instead of the parentheses for the function arguments. At that moment Xcode autocompleted my line by adding `.(τ_0_0)` as a suffix to the function name, where `τ_0_0` where treated as e.g. an internal name of a function w.r.t. Xcode autocompletion (to be overwritten).

`foo.(`<kbd>τ_0_0</kbd>`)`

Quick help (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+click) showed no information for this expansion, and every try to fill the expanded parenthesis with some value resulted in the error

> Error: Expected member name following '.'

**Question:** I'm curious, what does `τ_0_0` mean here? And can some kind of dot notation be used for a function in Swift?

---

**Prior research of my own**

My own research has led me to a swift file of tests (I think?) from the source code of Swift:

- https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/SILGen/functions.swift

I have only found `τ_0_0` in the comments of this file, however in comments marked by `// CHECK:`, so perhaps this is some code markup (much like `// MARK:`) that I simply haven't heard of before? I've found the following line to be of most interest (note that in the source this is a single (commented) line, that I've broken down here for ease of presentation)

```
// CHECK: [[CTOR_GEN:%[0-9]+]] =  
    function_ref @_TFC9functions11SomeGenericC{{.*}} :
    $@convention(thin) <τ_0_0> (@thick SomeGeneric<τ_0_0>.Type) 
    -> @owned SomeGeneric<τ_0_0>
```

Most notably the part `@_TFC9functions11SomeGenericC{{.*}}` for explaining the `.` notation, and part `(... SomeGeneric<τ_0_0>.Type)` for the `(...)` completion above. Everything in this line above is, however, beyond my Swift knowledge.

---

I am using Swift 2.1.1 and Xcode 7.2.

Comment: do you mean foo.(τ_0_0) ? I suggest you to fill a bug report, this kind of autocompletion we really don't need there :-) If we speak about foo().xy that is fine, if xy is a member of whatever is returned from function foo

Comment: @user3441734 Yes `foo.(τ_0_0)`, will edit, thanks! I'll see if someone knows if this is (in some way I can't understand myself) autocompletion has some meaning, otherwise possibly file a bug report.

Comment: so, put some return statement  ... ->Int { return 1 } in you first line of code

Comment: @dfri Off topic: thanks for your research on return false/true, I've raised a moderator flag based entirely upon the links you provided.

Comment: @matt That's good to hear, I raised one as well, but didn't actually include the links (just a reference to my comments), so possibly my flag was a bit light on information. Thanks.

Comment: @dfri OK cool, I was afraid you might not have raised the flag. I included a few of the links; there's a length limit, as with comments.