# what does τ_0_0 mean in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

I am not asking how to use the mapping I know how to use it
my question is when I use autocomplete I see this weird looking
string "τ_0_0"

```
let test = ["a":1,"b":2,"c":3] 
let kmToPoint = test.map { (<#(String, Int)#>) -> τ_0_0 in <#code#> }
```

what does `τ_0_0` mean ?

Comment: It's a type, probably defined somewhere in a library... Swift supports Unicode for identifiers, so it is legal.

Comment: Previously asked in [this un-answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822445/using-dot-notation-appended-to-generic-function-in-xcode-autocompletes-to-τ-0-0). Some additional details can be found there.

Comment: You see it littered about the SIL files at http://github.com/apple/swift. Looks like a placeholder for a generic's placeholder type in SIL.